# Connecting to Jira remotelly Using Netbeans or other client tools

Tags: netbeans, rpc, jira, jira-plugin, remote-connection

I am using Atlassian JIRA™ (Professional Edition, **Version: 3.0.3-#75** and Netbeans IDE 7.1
But when trying to validate a connection to Jira from netbeans it gave me this error "**Jira RPC  services are not enabled**"

while **I have enabled it** and also I **enabled allow remote calls** in Jira

To be more specific "RPC JIRA Plugin" that I have installed is

The standard JIRA RPC services, both SOAP and XML-RPC.
Plugin Version: 1.1
JIRA version: 3.0

It has
System XML-RPC Services (xmlrpc)
The standard JIRA XML-RPC services.
RPC Field Coordinator (rpcFieldCoordinator) 
Issue Service (issueService)
User Service (userService)
Token Manager (tokenManager)
System SOAP Services (soap)
The standard JIRA SOAP services. 
Magic Field Validator (magicFieldValidator) 
Project Service (projectService)

My global configurations are:
  Allow users to vote on issues     ON
  Allow users to watch issues   ON
  Allow unassigned issues   ON
  Cache issues  ON
  External user management  OFF
  Logout Confirmation   Never
  Use Gzip Compression  OFF
  Accept remote API calls   ON

BTW, it is not just netbeans, I got same problem with other tools as well to connect to jira

I will apreciate if my answer be found ASAP .
Thanks

Comment: JIRA 3.0.x is very old, way past end of life! But it should work with the JIRA Python CLI. ~Matt

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yep its older than my granddad! But our company don't want to spend more on Jira. However , I can't install any plug-in, just can do whatever can be done using it's UI.

Answer (score 3):

Answering an old question, but I thought someone else might find this useful.

I got the same error today setting up an issue tracker in NetBeans 7.2 and I eventually tracked it down to NetBeans not being able to correctly resolve (using DNS) the (local) host name that was running our JIRA server. When I changed NetBeans to use 'No Proxy' in the main settings, it worked fine.

---

EDIT: Note that as of version 7.0 of the JIRA server, Atlassian have [depracated the SOAP/XML-RPC API](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/latest-updates/soap-and-xml-rpc-api-deprecation-notice), so the JIRA Plugin for Netbeans no longer works. :-(